# 2D Array of UIButtons Isn't Working (Objective-C/iPhone development)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multidimensional-array

I've made a bunch of UIButtons in a grid and I want to be able to iterate over them easily so I've put them in an NSMutableArray.

Like so:

// in .h

UIButton* button1;
UIButton* button2;
...
UIButton* button9;

UIButton* myButtons[3][3];

// in init function in app

myButtons[0][0] = button1;
myButtons[0][1] = button2;
...
myButtons[2][2] = button9;

But now if I try to access the title of a button in myButtons I get nil:

// elsewhere in app
[button1 setTitle:@"A" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

// and then:
NSLog(@"currentTitle of button1: %@", (myButtons[0][0]).currentTitle); // -> (null)

Anybody know what's going on? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

first of all, that's not an `NSMutableArray`, it's just a plain ol' array.

Second, where do you set button1 to a non-null value?  Is it before or after assigning `myButtons[0][0] = button1;`?  I would check and make sure that `myButtons[0][0]` is non-null when calling the NSLog method.  If it is, then you need to assign your array later or assign the buttons earlier.